# How can I solve the segmentation fault in socket programing?

Tags: c, sockets, segmentation-fault

I have a problem in linux coding.

When I send file name to server, I get the `segmentation fault` in server.

It may happen in read.

But, I can't find any idea to solve it.

Any suggestions?

---

[image]

**Client Source code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define BUFMAX 256

void error_handling(const char *msg)
{
        fputs(msg, stderr);
        fputc('\n', stderr);
        exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int sockfd, h_err;
        int file_len = 0;
        int buf_size = 0;
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
        struct hostent *server;
        char buffer[BUFMAX];
        FILE *file;
        char *file_name;
        char *file_cont;

        if (argc < 2)
                error_handling("ERROR! No simulator provided\n");

        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sockfd < 0)
                error_handling("ERROR opening socket\n");

        memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);

        if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
                error_handling("ERROR connecting");

        // file handling
        file_name = (char *)malloc(strlen(argv[1]));
        file_len = strlen(argv[1]);
        memcpy(file_name, argv[1], file_len);
        file = fopen(file_name, "rb");
        if(file == NULL)
                error_handling("File is not exis!\n");

        // send file name
        h_err = write(sockfd, file_name, file_len);
        if(h_err < 0)
                error_handling("ERROR writing to socket!\n");

        // file handling
        fseek(file, 0, 2);
        file_len = ftell(file);
        fseek(file, 0, 0);

        // send file size
        memset(buffer, 0, BUFMAX);
        sprintf(buffer, "%d", file_len);
        h_err = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        if(h_err < 0)
                error_handling("ERROR writing to socket!\n");

        file_cont = (char *)malloc(file_len);
        while( !feof(file) )
        {
                fgets(buffer, BUFMAX, file);
                memcpy(file_cont + buf_size, buffer, strlen(buffer));
                buf_size = strlen(buffer);
        }
        h_err = send(sockfd, file_cont, file_len, 0);
        if(h_err < 0)
                error_handling("ERROR sending to socket");

        printf("File sending....\n");

        fclose(file);
        close(sockfd);

        return 0;
}
```

---

**Server Source code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define BUFMAX 8000

void error_handling(const char *msg)
{
        fputs(msg, stderr);
        fputc('\n', stderr);
        exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int sockfd, newsockfd, h_err;
        int file_len = 0;
        char buffer[BUFMAX];
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
        FILE *file;
        char *file_name;
        char file_cont[BUFMAX];
        socklen_t clilen;

        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sockfd < 0)
           error_handling("ERROR opening socket");

        memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
        if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
                    error_handling("ERROR on binding");

        listen(sockfd, 5);
        clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

        while(1)
        {
                newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
                if (newsockfd < 0)
                        error_handling("ERROR on accept");

                // receive file name
                memset(buffer, 0x00, BUFMAX);
                h_err = read(newsockfd, buffer, BUFMAX);
                if (h_err < 0)
                {
                        close(sockfd);
                        close(newsockfd);
                        error_handling("ERROR reading from socket");
                }
                strcpy(file_name, buffer);
                printf("File name = %s\n", file_name);

                // receive file size
                memset(buffer, 0, BUFMAX);
                h_err = read(newsockfd, buffer, BUFMAX);
                if (h_err < 0)
                {
                        close(sockfd);
                        close(newsockfd);
                        error_handling("ERROR reading from socket");
                }
                file_len = atoi(buffer);

                // file handling
                file = fopen(file_name, "wb");
                h_err = recv(newsockfd, file_cont, file_len, 0);
                if(h_err < 0)
                {
                        close(sockfd);
                        close(newsockfd);
                        error_handling("ERROR receive from socket");
                }
                printf("Recived client file\n");
                fwrite(file_cont, 1, file_len, file);

                close(newsockfd);
        }
        fclose(file);
        close(sockfd);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can solve it debugging your code...

Comment: You seem to forget that strings in C are actually one more character than `strlen` tells you, you forget the *terminator*.

Comment: I already trying debugging. but, I dont know why the read function read more than i send...

Comment: Also, TCP sockets are streaming, with no message boundaries and no guaranteed packet size. That means a single `read` call might not give you the whole message, and you might need to read in a loop to receive all data. And since TCP have no boundaries or packet sizes, there is no way to know when one "message" ends and another begins, unless you implement some kind of protocol atop TCP, for example always sending a fixed-size header containing the length of the data being transmitted, or you yourself adds some kind of separator.

Comment: And related to my previous comment, and to your problem with `read` reading more than you send, if you send two pieces of data from the client to the server, the server might read both (or one whole and a *part* of the next) pieces. You really need to think about designing some kind of protocol to know when one piece of data ends and the next begins.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks! I understand my problem!

Comment: Also, can you please elaborate on how the image is related to the crash? Can you please tell us, with e.g. a comment in the source code you show, where the crash happens? My guess about the crash though, the lack of zero-termination and that you don't have any message boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to debug your code.
I found that you forget to allocate memory size for var "file_name" in your server code.

Try to allocate for it like following line in your code.

`file_name = (char *)malloc(LEN_FILE_NAME);`

The problem can be solved.